Why can't I send messages to gmail in Java Spring via rabbitmq? Where am I going wrong?
I'm building a small project in spring, where I need to send the default password set by the superadmin to the admin's gmail address (I want to do it via rabbitmg, let me know if you have any other tips).  I'm using rabbitmq here, but after the message in the sent queue is unacked (localhost:15672 I can see this too), it is deleted instantly and even if the message reaches consumer, it is not sent to that gmail address.  What do you think is the reason?
RabbitMQConfig:
@Configuration 
public class RabbitMQConfig { 

@Bean 
public Queue emailQueue() {
 return new Queue("emailQueue",false); 
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange emailTopicExchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("emailTopicExchange",true,false);
}

@Bean
public Binding binding(Queue emailQueue, TopicExchange emailTopicExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(emailQueue).to(emailTopicExchange).with("email.key");
}

@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost("/");
    connectionFactory.setPort(5672);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
}

EmailProducer
@Service 
public class EmailProducer { 
private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

public EmailProducer(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
}

public void sendEmailMessage(String email, String password) {
    Map<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();
    message.put("email", email);
    message.put("password", password);
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("emailTopicExchange", "email.key", message);
}
}

EmailConsumer
@Service 
public class EmailConsumer {
private final MailService mailService;

public EmailConsumer(MailService mailService) {
    this.mailService = mailService;
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "emailQueue")
public void receiveMessage(Map<String, String> message)  {
    String email = message.get("email");
    String password = message.get("password");
    mailService.sendMail(email, password);
  
}
}

MailService:
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class MailService {
        final  JavaMailSender mailSender;
        public void sendMail(String email,String text) {
            SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
            message.setFrom(private);
            message.setTo(email);
            message.setText("Salam sizin admin passwordunuz: " + text);
            message.setSubject("Library Admin");
            mailSender.send(message);
        }
}

application.yml:
 mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    properties:
      mail:
        smtp:
          auth: true
          starttls:
            enable: true

    username: private
    port: 587
    password: private

  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

RabbitMQ has nothing to do with sending emails. Please isolate if you have problems with posting things to RabbitMQ, receiving them from RabbitMQ, or actually with sending email.

@MarkRotteveel Hi,  thanks for your answer about rabbitmq, I solved the problem, I just didn't use the given method in the right place.
